# How can I catch the FOE wandering around the big open area of B18F?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-untold

There's a FOE in the big open area of floor 18 that is resisting my attempts to engage it in combat. I don't currently know the FOE's name because I haven't been able to catch up to it. Every time I get close it teleports to the other side of the room. It looks like a plant bud.

It is foiling my goal to *kill all the things*. How can I catch up with this thing and murder it?

Comment: I recall this from the first edition of the game. However, as the terrain might be different this time around, I'm unsure if the same strategies will work. Let me rediscover what I actually did to catch the guy, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The World Bud, the FOE in question, doesn't teleport away based on how close you are to it. It just teleports to various corners of the room periodically. If you want to catch one of them just hang near one of the corners and walk around in circles and it'll eventually appear, at which point you can move in for the kill.